# Помогите пожалуйста исправить код

Tags: python

```
filename = input()

try:
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        text = file.read()
        for i in range(len(text)):
            if text[i] == "haha":
                text1 = text[i].replace("haha","[censored]")
                textf=text.replace(text[i], text)
        print(textf)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Файл не найден")
```

Напишите программу, принимающую на вход имя файла и заменяющего все вхождения слова ''haha'' на ''[censored]''.
Выведите на экран отцензурированную версию исходного файла. В случае отсутствия файла нужно вывести соответствующее сообщение об ошибке "Файл не найден".

Comment: Задание-чатгпт-не работает-стековерфлоу. Угадал?

Comment: Я слишком суров. В коде после чата видны ваши попытки заставить его работать. Это хорошо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy может это сам чат залогинился на стеке?

Comment: @AndyPavlov, чатгпт отключен от интернета в реальном времени. Его обучают на некотором слепке из недалёкого прошлого. В дальнейшем от получает информацию только из вопросов пользователей. Пока сам чат тут появится не может.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да я пошутил)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename = input("Название файла: ")

try:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        text = f.read().replace("haha", "[censored]")
        print(text)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Файл не найден")
```

при необходимости сохраняйте результат в файл, но согласно вашему условию результат нужно вывести на экран

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: @Timur.07 если ответ удовлетворяет вашему запросу, то можете принять его в качестве решения, нажав соответствующую кнопку слева от него. Спасибо